# Why JavaScript function visibility depends on declaration in the same or different script block in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

If I implement the following JavaScript code block in HTML markup:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunc() {
            alert(1);
        }
        var f1 = MyFunc;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunc() {
            alert(2)
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        f1();
    </script>
```

I get an alert message '1'.
However, if I use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function MyFunc() {
                alert(1);
            }
            var f1 = MyFunc;
            function MyFunc() {
                alert(2)
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            f1();
        </script>
```

I get '2'. Why?
Tested in IE10, latest FF, Chrome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each script element is parsed and executed in order. In the first case, the assignment to *f1* is made before the second declaration is processed.

In the second case, both declarations are parsed before the assignment is made (because **declarations are processed before any code is executed**), so the second declaration replaces the first before the assignment to *f1*.

Comment: But the function is passed by reference, so why does it matter, the script tags are clearly parsed in the order they appear in the DOM.

Comment: Correct, so in the first case *f1* references the first function before a new object is assigned to *MyFunc* by the second declaration. So *f1* continues to reference that first function after the value of *MyFunc* is changed to reference the second function.

Comment: @RobG: in the second case isn't the assignment statement parsed and executed before the myfunc is re-defined?

Comment: Variables are hoisted, so the reference is set before any function is defined, the question being, what does the script tags add that makes it no longer update the reference.

Comment: Note that in `var f1 = ...;` the declaration (i.e. the `var f1` part) is processed first with other declarations, the assignment (the `= MyFunc;` part) is processed in turn when code is executed.

Answer (score 16):

This is caused by *hoisting*. `var` and `function` declarations are hoisted to the top of the script block they are in.

This means that your first script essentially becomes:

```
var f1;
function MyFunc() {
    alert(1);
}
f1 = MyFunc;

// new script block

function MyFunc() {
    alert(2)
}

// new script block

f1(); // alert 1
```

Meanwhile, your second script becomes:

```
var f1;
function MyFunc() {
    alert(1);
}
function MyFunc() { // overwrite previous MyFunc
    alert(2)
}
f1 = MyFunc;

// new script block

f1(); // alert 2
```

I hope this makes sense - just in general avoid overwriting functions XD

Comment: +1 - first one that really got it, the others seems to be mostly guessing.

Comment: A good thing to suggest avoiding overwriting functions... It's nothing but confusing to do so.

Comment: @adeneo how is this answer any different from my answer.Mine uses simple language which is easy to understand whereas he described it fully which may go over the head for beginners

Comment: @Zword - I consider myself being intermediate in both english and javascript and I don't understand your answer at all, it has nothing to do with scope, local or global, and everything to do with hoisting and the way the tags are parsed.

Comment: I mention `similar to a local` which doesnt mean that i am specifying a function or variable as local.I m trying to tell that the `<script>` block in which `var f1` is defined it performs the function contained in that block

Answer (score 2):

For the first part with **alert message 1** the declaration `var f1 = MyFunc;` becomes similar to a local wrt different `<script>` blocks.Hence the `<script>` block in which `var f1` is defined it performs the function contained in that block.

For the second part with **alert message 2** , 1st MyFunc() is overwritten by the second.

Comment: The way `f1` is declared makes it a property of the global object, not a local variable, is it ?

Comment: **local** with respect to different `<script></script> blocks

Answer (score 2):

I hope I don't confuse anybody, but, I suspect the answer has something to do with scopes.

Here is my argument:

For the 1st case:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc() {
        alert(1);
    }
    var f1 = MyFunc;
   window.foo1 = MyFunc;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc() {
        alert(2)
    }
  window.foo2 = MyFunc;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    f1();
    alert(window.foo2 === window.foo1);
</script>
```

The second alert will issue a false.

Now the 2nd case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function MyFunc() {
                alert(1);
            }
            var f1 = MyFunc;
            window.foo1 = f1;
            function MyFunc() {
                alert(2)
            }
            window.foo2 = MyFunc;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            f1();
            alert(window.foo1 === window.foo2);
        </script>
```

The second alert will issue a true.

It kind of shows that (for 1st case) MyFunc is redefined and is a totally different "object" when the 2nd script block is processed. `f1` holds a reference to the first "object" in the first script block. Hence `f1()` alerts `1`.